# A French version of Rebel

Tags: nlp, transformer, knowledge-base, knowledge-graph

Is there an end-to-end trained transformer like Rebel for french data?
Rebel can extract entities and relations from text, yet as far as I know, it works only with english texts.
Is there any other alternatives for **french** data? I am working in building a knowledge graph of my french (after translating it) data using Rebel, but it didn't work well.

I tried to translate my french data to english. I already have a very noisy data, it becomes even noisier after translation, so I am looking for altenative of Rebel, an end-to-end architecture that deals with **french** data.